# Carbon Creating Date From String

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Hello I have the following line of code in my application:

```
$deposit = new BankDeposit();
$deposit->date_occurred = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->date_occurred);
$deposit->amount = $request->amount;
$deposit->save();
```

where `$request->date_occurred` is **19/10/2016**.
Now something funny is happening, when I post this data from my android app and to the server, the server receives the date but somehow parses and saves it as

> 0016-10-19 08:48:14

However when I post from postman using exactly the same values I did in the android app I get:

> 2016-10-19 08:48:14

I've inspected both requests and I can't tell what is wrong.
This is the request and response when I use postman:

```
{
  "request": {
    "date_occurred": "19/10/2016",
    "amount": "5000"
  },
  "response": {
    "date_occurred": "2016-10-19 08:52:33",
    "amount": "5000",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-06 08:52:33",
    "created_at": "2016-10-06 08:52:33",
  }
}
```

This is what I see when I log the response in my android monitor:

```
{
    "request": {
        "date_occurred": "19\/10\/16",
        "amount":"2323"
    },
    "response": {
        "date_occurred": "0016-10-19 08:48:14",
        "amount": "2323",
        "created_at": "2016-10-06 08:48:14",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-06 08:48:14"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your android app is not sending the "Y" year notation. But it's sending in y.

Comment: So what do I do about it? Why can't Carbon recognize 16(y) as 2016(Y)?